# R: take 2 random non-overlapping samples (for same indexes) of length n out of vector of length n as well

Tags: r, replace, overlap, sample

Say I have a vector named `all_combinations` with numbers from 1 to 20.

I need to extract 2 vectors (`coding_1` and `coding_2`) of length equal to `number_of_peptide_clusters`, which happens to be 20 as well in my current case.

The 2 new vectors should be randomly sampled from `all_combinations`, so that are not overlapping at each index position.

I do the following:

```
set.seed(3)
all_combinations=1:20
number_of_peptide_clusters=20
coding_1 <- sample(all_combinations, number_of_peptide_clusters, replace = FALSE)
coding_1
 [1]  5 12  7  4 10  8 11 15 17 16 18 13  9 20  2 14 19  1  3  6
coding_2 <- sample(all_combinations, number_of_peptide_clusters, replace = FALSE)
coding_2
 [1]  5  9 19 16 18 12  8  6 15  3 13 14  7  2 11 20 10  4 17  1
```

This is the example that gives me trouble, cause only one number is overlapping at the same index (5 at position 1).

What I would do in these cases is spot the overlapping numbers and resample them out of the list of all overlapping numbers...

Imagine `coding_1` and `coding_2` were:

```
coding_1
 [1]  5 9  7  4 10  8 11 15 17 16 18 13  12 20 2  14 19  1  3  6
coding_2
 [1]  5 9 19 16 18 12  8  6 15  3 13 14  7  2  11 20 10  4 17  1
```

In this case I would have 5 and 9 overlapping in the same position, so I would resample them in `coding_2` out of the full list of overlapping ones [resample index 1 from `c(5,9)` so that isn't equal to `5`, and index 2 so it isn't equal to `9`]. So `coding_2` would be:

```
coding_2
 [1]  9 5 19 16 18 12  8  6 15  3 13 14  7  2  11 20 10  4 17  1
```

However, in the particular case above, I cannot use such approach... So what would be the best way to obtain 2 samples of length 20 from a vector of length 20 as well, so that the samples aren't overlapping at the same index positions?

It would be great that I could obtain the second sample `coding_2` already knowing `coding_1`... Otherwise obtaining the 2 at the same time would also be acceptable if it makes things easier. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider that the length is not always 20, and, while `coding_1` and `coding_2` always have the same length, `all_combinations` can be either equal or larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is simply to use a rejection strategy:

```r
set.seed(3)
all_combinations <- 1:20
number_of_peptide_clusters <- 20
count <- 0
repeat {
  count <- count + 1
  message("Try number ", count)
  coding_1 <- sample(all_combinations, number_of_peptide_clusters, replace = FALSE)
  coding_2 <- sample(all_combinations, number_of_peptide_clusters, replace = FALSE)
  if (!any(coding_1 == coding_2))
    break
}
#> Try number 1
#> Try number 2
#> Try number 3
#> Try number 4
#> Try number 5
#> Try number 6
#> Try number 7
#> Try number 8
#> Try number 9
coding_1
#>  [1] 18 16 17 12 13  8  6 15  3  5 20  9 11  4 19  2 14  7  1 10
coding_2
#>  [1]  5 20 14  2 11  6  7 10 19  8  4  1 15  9 13 17 18 16 12  3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>